# TFS 2012, Build Extensions for ANT

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ant, tfs

anyone know where I can find the Build Extensions for TFS 2012 that target Visual Studio 2012 DLL's. I can find the 2005, 2008, 2010 and 2013 build extensions that fulfil this requirement but I cannot for the life of me locate the one for 2012. This is required as I get the following exception when attempting to run my build definition.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\BuildExtensions\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Extensions.Ant.targets (256): The "Ant" task failed unexpectedly.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This was tried after installing the 2013 extensions found here : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2011f516-15a7-4f9a-8b86-1e0894a75739

This is clearly targeting a 2013 DLL which my build machine hasn't got installed, is this a case of the 2012 build extensions not being available anymore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a fair amount of digging about and hair pulling, I was able to get hold of the official MS version of this, though when [visiting the download page is see](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45b4e378-5b81-4186-9b7f-21cc5c2f743d)

> "This item is not yet published."

I'm guessing then that support was pulled for the 2012 version of this, though I can't see any reference as to why? However I was able to find a [direct link (power of google) to the MSI installer in the VS gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45b4e378-5b81-4186-9b7f-21cc5c2f743d/file/83776/4/Visual%20Studio%20Team%20Foundation%20Server%202012%20Update%202%20Build%20Extensions.msi).

Answer (score 0):

This is so hard to accept, build extensions for ant can be found for all TFS versions except 2012.